# Extracting contacts from broken phone

Tags: contacts

I've broken the glass of my LG G2. Touch is not working. Although I can still connect the phone via USB and see its contents. I want to extract contacts and copy them to my new Android phone.

The phone is not rooted.

Yes, I had sync with my gmail account, but for some reason many contacts where not synced.

Is there anything I could do?

Comment: Although touch is not working, can you read the screen? If yes, then does you device support OTG? If true, then buy an OTG cable and use a standard mouse with it and install a contacts backup app from Play Store to make backup of your contacts. ( [tag:adb] can't backup the contacts.)

Comment: Also, you can try to sync contacts if your OTG is working.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to access the contacts data on an unrooted phone using a file  explorer.

You may be able to use "**[LG PC Suite](http://www.lg.com/hk_en/support/pc-suite)**" to control and manage the phone from your PC.

As a final option, have you thought of having the phone repaired? Lots of glass replacement businesses out there. Many will  fix while you wait.

Comment: Linked has been added